# What's happening with this table? Maybe an open transaction lock?

Tags: sql-server

When I try to run drop table command, MSSQL is just hanging, and saying "executing command" forever
I think this has something to do with a lock?

How do I bug check this type of query?

Comment: One method that will possibly help, is to restart the server, and immediately after booting up (and before any application hits it), try your DROP command. Second method would be to include the DROP command code in your question for us to see and troubleshoot. And finally, maybe (if possible) some of the code that accesses the table, which you think could be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSSQL have sp `sp_lock` to find lock tables. Try it.

Reference : http://www.sqlhub.com/2009/07/find-table-being-locked-in-sql-server.html

Comment: OK, this is showing the table which has the problem. How do I fix it?

Comment: You figure out what is locking it. There's no silver bullet here. If you have a long-running transaction elsewhere, the lock is good. If you have forgotten to close a transaction/connection somewhere, it isn't. Impossible to tell until you've figured out where the lock comes from.

Comment: I'm sure I locked it by mistake, is there a way to kill all locks on the table? I'm pretty sure it's just locked by some earlier non important queries i was running.

Comment: Queries do not lock tables indefinitely - unless you have transaction open. Do you?

Comment: @Waller : If you want to kill the lock then just try this `kill @SPID` - @SPID is a Process ID

Comment: Well I haven't used any BEGIN commands at all on this table.. I'm not even sure why this transaction has locked open. I'm thinking it's some kind of mistake. I really just want to get rid of this table, Im confident there must be some kind of work around. Times like this I wish I had a DBA to hand, I'm a bit of of my league here.

Comment: @pandian, i have typed kill 68 (myspid) it says command successful, i then type drop table dbo.codepoint_latest and it gets stuck again. This is so frustrating. I'm going to the pub in the hopes of fixing this one.

Comment: @Waller : try `sp_who2` and find which process are running longtime and which makes your process lock and then `kill` the process